# Why doesn't my new SRAM XG-1295 cassette bolt turn freely?

Tags: cassette, sram

I am trying to install a brand new SRAM XG-1295 cassette. I watched many videos and it seems very straight forward. Place the cassette on the freehub, match the splines in back, tighten with a cassette tool.

But for some reason, the bolt(?) on the cassette does not turn. This has nothing to do with the freehub. I'm holding the cassette in my hand, trying to turn the bolt but it does not turn.

[image]
Any help would be appreciated :)

-MIke

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when 'it doesn't turn'? Do you mean that it's hard to turn? DO you feel like it's stuck? even if you don't use your hand on the cassette to counteract the rotation of the tool, the pawls of the freehub should stop the rotation and enable you to thread in the cassette.

Comment: I think you mean locking rather than bolt

Comment: Bolt? Can you put a picture or something? I'm not sure what bolt you'd have, since you should just be putting it on and tightening a lockring.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried to make a little video. And then realized that you can't upload video here. #facepalm.
Yes, I meant the locking nut. @ArgentiApparatus

It turns out that it was just VERY stuck.  I can barely turn it now, but I can turn it.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you solved the problem, so I'm going to hijack this thread slightly to provide some general info. The cassette you have uses the SRAM "XD" technology, which is unusual in using a "lock tube" instead of a traditional lock ring. The lock tube is integrated into the cassette and enables the cassette to have the otherwise too small 10-tooth cog. The tube is the part marked in the OP's photo.

Although the OP's problem is with the movement of the locktube within the cassette, there have been a number of complaints in the past few years about the locktube seizing against the freehub, since there is a significant surface area of contact between them. Compounding the problem is the fact that the splines on the lock tube have a very low profile, so when excessive torque is applied to try to turn a seized lock tube, the splines shear off. Very often the result is that both the cassette and freehub body must be replaced. Search "SRAM XD cassette seizing up" for stories.

The take-home message is that you should liberally apply grease or anti-seize to the freehub body whenever installing this type of cassette!

Answer (score 3):

I'll add an update for those who come looking for help with this...AS I DID! I called SRAM tech support, and they said the tube not spinning in a new XG1195 (X01 10-42 11 speed) cassette is normal. The tech told me if the tube spun freely by hand on a new cassette that would likely be a problem. The tech told me thread it on with the proper ParkTool FR-5.2GT tool (which I have) and take your wrench to it. When it bottoms out, use your inch pound torque wrench and tighten to 40NM. I asked about peoples comments in forums saying people break the tabs with that tightening spec, and he said if your tools are good and your torque wrench is remotely accurate, in no way should that be a concern!

Comment: Dave, great info. Please update if you get any additional info so we can get it captured. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact issue - a new SRAM XG-1295 cassette whose lock tube would not turn. Since it was new I didn't want to apply too much force and strip the splines or break something.   After reading this and a few other discussions it became clear that the lock tube was probably stuck. I put a bit of chain lube between the smallest cog and the large shiny clip that holds the cogs to the lock tube.  After giving it a couple of minutes to penetrate I tried to get the lock tube to move and it freed up with much less force, but not too easily. It was too tight to hand-turn which made me a little nervous threading it onto the rotor with a big wrench.  All is well though, it went on just fine without cross-threading - time to ride!

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that the locking nut mechanism was stuck. This is a $495 cassette so obviously I didn't want to force the thing for nothing.

I put the tool in a vice and wrapped a chain whip around the cassette and forced it. It made a little snap sounds and now it moves, though not very freely. Usually you can hand tighten to start off, I'll have to use a tool the whole way.

Thanks to those who commented and tried to help :)

Comment: If you just bought it, you could've sent a complaint to the store. That 'snap' could've been a manufacturing defect or some kind of corrosion breach.
Anyways, what's done is done.

Answer (score 0):

The "lock tube" advice was very useful.  I tried cleaning it with brake cleaner, but it froze up the lock tube.  Then I tried penetrating oil, but WD-40 did the trick.

The lock tube is not spinning freely though.  I can only turn it with the splined tool and a wrench.  Also I was very careful installing the cassette since I'm sure it can easily strip.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  I can't tell if you're offering a solution or you're explaining that you still have issues.  If you have a problem that isn't answered on this question then you should post your own question, explaining what you're having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said: it is normal for the lock tube on an XD cassette to be very stiff when new. You want to get it moving before you try to install the cassette. My solution was similar to OP: put a drop of penetrating oil where the lock tube meets the small cog, lay the cassette flat on a bench, use chain-whip/lock-ring tool/wrench to get the lock tube moving.